# perl. convert 64-bit binary number to decimal

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I have a string contains 64 binary symbols.

I need to convert it into the decimal number. How can I do it in perl?

```
sub bin2dec {
    return unpack("N", pack("B64", substr("0" x 64 . shift, -64)));
}
```

doesn't work. it converts just first 32 bit.

Comment: Probably the first thing to consider is if your perl is built with 64 bit support, but I'm not completly sure if it's 100% dependent on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html),

```
N  An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.
```

The 64 bit equivalent would be "`Q>`".

```
q  A signed quad (64-bit) value.
Q  An unsigned quad value.
  (Quads are available only if your system supports 64-bit
  integer values _and_ if Perl has been compiled to support
  those. Raises an exception otherwise.)

>   sSiIlLqQ   Force big-endian byte-order on the type.
    jJfFdDpP   (The "big end" touches the construct.)
```

So you could use the following:

```
unpack("Q>", pack("B64", substr("0" x 64 . shift, -64)))
```

---

That said, the above is needlessly complicated. Whoever coded that was was probably not aware of [`oct`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html)'s ability to parse binary numbers because the above can be reduced to

```
oct("0b" . shift)
```

---

But what do you do if you don't have a 64-bit build of Perl? You need to use some kind of object that overloads math operations. You could use [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aBigInt), but I suspect that won't be nearly as fast as [Math::Int64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aInt64).

```
use Math::Int64 qw( string_to_int64 );
string_to_int64(shift, 2)
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MMath::Int64=string_to_int64 -E'say string_to_int64(shift, 2);' \
   100000000000000000000000000000000
4294967296
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use Math::BigInt;
my $b = Math::BigInt->new('0b1010000110100001101000011010000110100001101000011010000110100001');
print $b;
```

Just the idea, not an equivalent code to your subroutine.
The binary number here is an arbitrary one. Use yours.

Comment: +1 (I like this!) ..or just simply `print Math::BigInt->new('0b' . $binaryStr);`